# ESLint настройка в VS Code: табуляция и окончание строка

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, eslint

Есть голый проект созданный Vue CLI, где ESLint не ругается на 2 пробела, используемых в качестве табуляции (отступа уровня кода).

И есть мой конфиг:

```
{
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,

    "[json]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    ...
}
```

т.е. мне необходимо что бы размер табуляции был 4 пробела, но Alt+Shift+F (автоформат) или просто установка 4х пробелов вместо 2х:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Вопрос первый**: как сказать ESLint какой размер табуляции мне нужен?

---

**Вопрос второй**: чего хочет ESLint в конце строк?
Вроде бы можно ставить ; но если поставить, то ругается...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а при отсутствии подчеркивает зеленым

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Информации по настройке этого зверя не нашел, в сети.
По крайней мере, в форме понятной что это именно то что нужно))

---

Если у ESLint нет настроек, то подскажите другой плагин VS Code для Vue.js

Comment: Точки с запятыми лишние, а по поводу зеленой обводки, он говорит что ожидает размер таба в 2 пробелах но у тебя 4)

Comment: Ага, но ES6 позволяет ставить ; И нужно переучить с 2 на 4 пробела. Как?

Comment: Твой конфиг, там видишь написано: `'editor.tabSize': 4`, для javascript меняешь на 2)

Comment: Мне не 2 нужно, а именно 4 !!!  VS я для этого и настроил! Как ESLint настроить?

Comment: Сорян) Не дочитал вопрос, сейчас посмотрю у себя)

Comment: Посмотри [**тут на сайте**](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) , а в VSCode надо эту настройку добавить сюда: [фото](http://prntscr.com/kgjinx)

Comment: Да, спасибо, получилось:

    "eslint.options": {
        "rules": {
            "indent": [2, 4]
        }
    }

Comment: А с точкой запятой в конце строк бороться?

Comment: А это уже не знаю, думаю также через опции можно найти и отключить вообще эту функциональность

Comment: Ок, тогда ответьте на вопрос, что бы я мог закрыть вопрос

Comment: Норм статья. Собраны все плагины для vs code
https://use-web.ru/news.php?id=139&tid=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчёт настрокий отступов в ESLint, то это можно загялнуть сюда: [ESLint indent rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent), а в VSCode просто надо написать это правило под себя и добавить сюда в настройках VSCode: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помимо отступов, можно настроить много чего, или же просто отключать эти правила, про всё это можно посотреть тут в [настройках правил в ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/)

Comment: Да, спасибо, получилось: "eslint.options": { "rules": { "indent": [2, 4] } }